# Getting the text of a dynamic element in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating input fields dynamically, hoping to parse any text entered in a field and process in the keydownFunc later. No text avail in the DOM after the key event occurred.

Here is my code:

```js
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.setAttribute("style", "width:33px;");
  element.setAttribute("name", i);
  element.setAttribute("onkeydown", "keydownFunc(event);");
  var tempID = document.getElementById(i)
  tempID.appendChild(element);

}

function keydownFunc(event) {
  var x = event.keyCode;
  if (x == 13 | x == 9) {
    path = event.path[1].id
    console.log(path);
    //           process input
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <td id="1"></td>
    <td id="2"></td>
    <td id="3"></td>
    <td id="4"></td>
    <td id="5"></td>
    <td id="6"></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The code you've written here works for me.  Is there something else you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid assigning event handlers using `on...` attributes. You should  use `addEventListener` instead:

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", keydownFunc);
```

Also `path` is a quite obscure and not a standard property of the Event object. What are you trying to access? If it's the input itself, then use `event.target` (for example `event.target.value` to get its value), or if you want to get the table cell, then use `event.target.parentNode`.

Comment: event.target.value did the trick. Please comment on why I should avoid the on.. attributes assignment and if it's b-coz of standard practices or because it may cause some trouble on the code eventually, thanks

Comment: Both. It standard practice, and it can lead to trouble. An `on...` can only hold a single handler, so it could be accidently overwritten by another script. That can't happen with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but I think you want to access the text someone has entered in the textbox and do something with it.  You can access this inside of your `keydownFunc` as

```
event.path[0].value
```

Here `event.path[0]` will be the input element.

Incidentally you don't need to name the input element, unless you're using the name for something else.